# Is there an updated version of Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro that has been released?

Tags: sony-xperia-x10-mini-pro, sony-xperia-mini-pro

I went to the [Taipei Computer Applications Show 2011](http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=sony%20xperia%20mini%20pro%20ii&ei=UTF-8&fr=moz35) today and bought a Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro from the Sony Ericsson booth there. However, the specs don't seem to match the [one on GSM Arena for Xperia X10](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_ericsson_xperia_x10_mini_pro-3147.php) at all. Mine shows Android version as 2.3 Gingerbread, a 1 GHz processor, and an HVGA display instead. Is this a legit version or have I just bought a very sophisticated brick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Xperia Mini Pro](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/products/mobilephones/overview/xperia-mini-pro?cc=ph&lc=en) and the [Xperia X10 Mini Pro](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/corporate/products/phoneportfolio/specification/xperiax10minipro) are actually different phones.  Confusing, I know.  [The former appears to be a "refreshed" version of the latter](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19736_7-20060195-251.html) with your specs.

Comment: Interesting. From that news item, it would appear I have bought a version of the phone not released yet officially?

Comment: @Ankur Possibly. Looks like [it might have been released in India](http://www.unwiredview.com/2011/07/25/sony-ericsson-xperia-mini-and-mini-pro-to-arrive-in-india-this-week/), I didn't see anything about elsewhere.